# AngularJS How to access parameter of one ngController in another ngController

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scope, ng-controller

Here is the thing:

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
   <div ng-controller="controller2" ng-init="controller2.someMethod(controller1.Data.someId)">
      {{something}}
   </div>
</div>
```

For some reason I can't access `controller1.Data.someId` in the *div* of the other controller, but I really need to pass this ID to the other controller's method.

How could this be possibly done?

#### UPDATE:

```
<div ng-controller="routesController as routesCtrl">
    <div class="ps-top-space-1" ng-controller="routeController as routeCtrl" ng-init="loadFromRouteInfoScreen(routesCtrl.RoutesData.apiRouteInfoResponse)">
        <ons-button modifier="large" ng-click="routeCtrl.addTickAndRouteRating()">Rate route or Add tick...</ons-button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where *routesCtrl.RoutesData.apiRouteInfoResponse* is set in the *routesController* and should have a data object with the *route_id*.
My method `loadFromRouteInfoScreen(route_id)` is triggering some other functions (and a `console.log`).

Comment: With the setup above, controller2's $scope inherits from controller1's $scope. So if you set in controller1 $scope.value = 7, then you can access it from controller2 $scope.value.

Comment: Create a service to share data between controllers, it can get messy working with parent/child relationships in controllers.

Comment: It turns out that my only problem is that if I pass the whole object (controller1.Data.apiResponse) it will be passed to the method correctly, however I only need "controller1.Data.apiResponse.data.someId" from it, which I can't get for some reason...

Comment: Can you log `controller1.Data.apiResponse` and show the structure in your question?

Comment: Yes and I see the data object with the id property:
abortDeferer
 
 Deferred { promise=Promise,  resolve=function(),  reject=function(),  more...}
data
 
 Object { route_id=139,  route_name="Fialová",  route_build_date_iso="2015-01-12",  more...}
error

Comment: You need to edit the question to add that code. There are serious problems with your code including that you are manufacturing a promise using `Promise` which is not integrated with the AngularJS framework.

Comment: Changes to scope made with the `.then` method of a JavaScript Promise will not be seen until something triggers an AngularJS digest cycle.

Comment: I have edited my question with real code (not the whole one though)..

Comment: Hehh, well right now I don't know which answer to pick as the correct one, as it seems that more are OK.
However I found the problem, for some reason the data in apiRouteInfoResponse wasn't accessible.
What I did was that I've assigned the required route_id into RoutesData.apiRouteInfoResponse.routeId and I was able to send this id from controller1 into controller2... My bad that it didn't work before :(

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo on the first controller- `ng-contoller="controller1"`. If that gets corrected, then the controller will be created correctly, and *controller2* will inherit the scope from *controller1* (refer to the Angular docs for [Scope inheritance](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#scope-inheritance-example)) and see the example below.

Also note that in the HTML we don't need to reference the controller variable - omit that object, since we can access properties on the scope directly. So instead of:

```
<div ng-controller="controller2" ng-init="controller2.someMethod(controller1.Data.someId)">
```

Do this:

```
<div ng-controller="controller2" ng-init="someMethod(Data.someId)">
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller1', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.Data = {
      someId: 3
    };
    $scope.something = 'something text';
  }
]);
app.controller('controller2', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.someMethod = function(id) {
      console.log('id: ', id, ' $scope.Data: ', $scope.Data);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="controller1">
    <div ng-controller="controller2" ng-init="someMethod(Data.someId)">
      {{something}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Update:

Since you updated your question to have more detail (e.g. Controllers specified with an alias), I have taken that angular HTML and alterred it to the code below. Notice how you don't really need to reference the aliases within the inline calls?

And note that I did simplify the button so we don't need an extra directive for that.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('routesController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    console.log('routesController created');
    $scope.RoutesData = {
      apiRouteInfoResponse: "43 miles"
    };
    $scope.something = 'something text';
    $scope.addTickAndRouteRating = function() {
      console.log('addTickAndRouteRating() called');
    };
    $scope.loadFromRouteInfoScreen = function(response) {
      console.log('loadFromRouteInfoScreen() called - response:',response);
    };
  }
]);
app.controller('routeController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.someMethod = function(id) {
      console.log('id: ', id, ' $scope.Data: ', $scope.Data);
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="routesController as routesCtrl">
    <div class="ps-top-space-1" ng-controller="routeController as routeCtrl" ng-init="loadFromRouteInfoScreen(RoutesData.apiRouteInfoResponse)">
      <button modifier="large" ng-click="addTickAndRouteRating()">Rate route or Add tick...</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I get undefined on Data.someId .... and yes I've made a typo, but in the code there isn't any :)

Comment: where is the assignment of the *Data* object? in controller1? if it isn't, can it be moved there (like in my example above)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- REPLACE
<div ng-contoller="controller1">
-->
<div ng-controller="controller1">
<!--        ^ --- spell controller correctly --> 
   <div ng-controller="controller2" ng-init="someMethod(Data.someId)">
      {{something}}
   </div>
</div>
```

As long as there is no `Data` property on the child scope, it will prototypically inherit from the parent scope.

Comment: I think there is Data property on the controller2 (at least "someMethod" is setting triggering functions for response data)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Controller As` syntax to make it clear whether you're referencing a parent or child variable in a nested scope.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('controller1', function() {
  var vm = this;

  this.something = 'hello';

  vm.Data = {
    someId: 123
  };
});

myApp.controller('controller2', function() {
  var vm = this;

  this.something = 'world';

  this.someMethod = function(someId) {
    console.log('someId: ' + someId);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="controller1 as ctrl1">
    <div ng-controller="controller2 as ctrl2"
         ng-init="ctrl2.someMethod(ctrl1.Data.someId)">
      {{ctrl1.something}} {{ctrl2.something}}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: yeah, this basically is what I already have, my code was just a quick example.